# migrate 10g xe to 11g xe

Tags: oracle10g, upgrade, oraclexe, data-extraction, oracle-11g

The oracle 10g DB that is being currently used has exceeded the limit of 4GB. For the application to continue the db needs to be upgraded to 11g. But the upgrade doc requires a data pump export to be done from 10g and then data pump import it to 11g.

But the concern is the 10g exceeding its limit of 4GB and hence will not allow a data pump export to be done. Is there any alternate option to move the data to 11g other than data pump export and import.

Have tried the export with expdp but i get an error saying the database has exceeded th 4gb limit.

Comment: Have you *tried* the export? If so, what error message(s) did you get?  -- Also this question might to better on http://dba.stackexchange.com - add the information above and we can move it for you.

Comment: Have edited my post. I ried the 'expdp' option. But i get the atabase has exceeded 4GB limit and does not proceed.

Comment: The issue was resolved. Since this question is not closed. If anybody stumbles into here with a similar issue. The resolution is here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18131/oracle-10g-xe-to-11g-xe-upgrade